# Double condition if statements in MIPS

Tags: c, mips

I'm converting the following C code into MIPS and it appears that the `isIdent` function always return 0.

C: [full code here](https://pastebin.com/BzPP4E7V)

```
int isIdent (int m[N][N], int n)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
            if (row == col && m[row][col] != 1)
                return 0;
            else if (row != col && m[row][col] != 0)
                return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

MIPS:
[isIdent code here](https://pastebin.com/99tMy18y) [Full code here](https://pastebin.com/ubWtYf8R)

I have tried changing the positions of the if statements e.g. checking `row` and `col` first however it doesn't seem to make a difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are not _fetching_ `m[row][col]`. You are just calculating its address. In your code, after the `addu`, do: `ld $t0,0($t0)` to actually fetch the value

Comment: Include all of the code you need us to look at in the question.  Do not include a link and expect us to follow it.

Comment: Sorry forgot to include them! Have added links to the full code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found the [solution](https://pastebin.com/2g4WxP1r)! What I had to do was actually fetch the value from the address calculated, as @CraigEstey pointed out.

```
# m[row][col] = *(&m[0][0] + (row * N) + col)
mul $t0, $s2, $s1   # % <- row * N
add $t0, $t0, $s3   #    + col
li  $t1, 4
mul $t0, $t0, $t1   #    * sizeof(word)
addu    $t0, $s0, $t0   #    + &m[0][0]
lw  $a0, ($t0)      # actually fetch m[r][c] from memory
```

Thanks a lot guys :)